# How to automate printing messages in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, list, automation

How do I print, separated by tabs, the values of all the strings in a list without prior knowledge of the number of strings in a list?

If I knew that the list has just 3 elements, I could do something like this:

```
l = ['A', 'B', 'C']
print "\t".join([l[0], l[1], l[2]])
```

And I would obtain

```
A       B       C
```

But I have no idea of how to do it for `n` strings in a automated way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
l = ['A', 'B', 'C']
print "\t".join(l)
```

Now just in case your lists contains several lists within them:

```
import itertools

l = ['A', 'B', 'C', ['d', 'D']]
foo = [item for item in itertools.chain(*l)]
print "\t".join(foo)
```

Comment: omg now Im feeling like a bit stupid, it was so easy... Thank you very much

Comment: There's really nothing stupid in something that we do not know. Reading the docs would definitely help a lot. Glad to help you.

Comment: Why do you use list comprehension to create a list identical to the original list? Just use `foo = "\t".join(l)` instead.

Comment: I was planning to expand this answer that a list that contains collections within them may require a different approach. Edited

Comment: @Eduard An exception will occur if the main list contains nested lists deeper than 1 level. Like:  `l = ['A', 'B', ['C', 'D', ['E']]]` will cause `TypeError: sequence item 4: expected string, list found`.

Comment: That is true indeed, after a few search, this would be the best solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists

Answer (score 3):

> `l = ['A','B','C']`
>
> `joined_string = "\t".join(l)`
>
> `print joined_string`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
>>> l = ['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> foo = "\t".join(l)
>>> print foo
```

Will output:

```
A   B   C
```